# trying to click a html button with selenium with python

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium4

Trying to go trough a website using selenium to parse some stuff,
but i cant click it on a button to load a pop up java script page

using firefox + geckowebdriver (latest)

```
view_larger_image_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="View larger image"]')
driver.click(view_larger_image_button)
```

Here is the button :

```
<div class="main-link" data-spm-anchor-id="a2700.details.0.i4.2b7b5fc5f54UAP"><i class="detail-next-icon detail-next-icon-search detail-next-small"></i><span>View larger image</span></div>
```

i get the following error:

```
  File "image.py", line 17, in <module>
    view_larger_image_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="View larger image"]')
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` methods are deprecated in current Selenium versions. You need to use `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, " ")`, `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, " ")` etc. methods.
So, instead of `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="View larger image"]')`
you should use

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[text()="View larger image"]')
```

You will also need this import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```